# Free Weight Exercises

Tags: exercise

I'm lokking for home exercises that I can do easily. I'm looking to see a photo or video and apply the exercise, do you know any good free or paid websites for this thing?

Comment: Are you interested in Body Weight? or Free Weight (Free weights are barbell/dumbbell exercises)?

Answer (score 2):

From your question it is not clear whether you have access to barbells (free weights) or not.  If you do, or are willing to get some, I recommend reading this article: [Intro to Strength Training](http://ironstrong.org/index.php?/topic/65-intro-to-strength-training/) which will help you get started.

For beginners the two best programs to begin with are [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.com) and [StrongLifts 5x5](http://stronglifts.com).  The article I linked to at the beginning has a few thoughts on choosing between them.  Both programs have articles that demonstrate the lifts you would be doing.  Mark Rippetoe (Starting Strength) even has a number of videos on YouTube to help demonstrate and teach good technique.

If you purchase barbells brand new, you can get them as cheap as $300 USD for a barbell and and weights to get up to 300lb.  You can also find them used on Craig's List or Ebay, so there are other low cost options to get you started.  That will be more than enough to get you going, and by the time you are ready to buy a better barbell/weights you will be pretty strong and better know what you really need.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend Mark Sisson's [Primal Blueprint Fitness](http://www.marksdailyapple.com/introducing-primal-blueprint-fitness/). It focuses around 5 essential full-body movements, and is designed for beginners and advanced persons alike. It does not require any expensive equipment and is extremely effective. I have been following this plan and love it.

Mark also provides a wealth of health and fitness information as well as a vibrant community at [marksdailyapple.com](http://www.marksdailyapple.com/). But most importantly, in regards to home exercises, he provides each week a [Workout of the Week](http://www.marksdailyapple.com/primal-blueprint-fitness/workout-of-the-week-archive/) which is designed to keep your fitness routine from getting mundane and keeping it exciting and fresh.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a huge fan of Matt Furey's stuff. His free articles are at http://www.mattfurey.com/articles.html, but the books are excellent as well. Combat Conditioning and Combat Abs are my favorites.

It's mostly centered on the "Royal Court," the Hindu Squat, Hindu Pushup, and Neck Bridge, all of which are well known bodyweight exercises and can easily be looked up on the net.

Answer (score 0):

[ExRX](http://www.exrx.net/Lists/Directory.html) is a good resource for exercises with short video clips for different muscles.  However, nothing beats spending time with a trainer to learn proper form.

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest looking into youtube specially the "Buff dudes" and "Athleanx" as most of the stuff is quite informative and free. Also you can easily make dumbells and weight plates using concrete and it is way much cheap :P